# running npm application using forever start in server

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, forever

I have an angular 6 application with typescript and webpack.

This angular application has backend for serving api calls and the backend is running as a separate application.

To start the application in my local, From the project home folder,

> **npm start**

To build the application,

> **npm run build**

When I run the above command, I get, dist folder which has the follwoings.

```
- index.html
- assets
    - fonts
    - icon
    - img
- main.sdgsdgfdsff.css
- main.sdfgsdfgdsfg.js
- manifest.3asdasdfsad.bundle.js
- polyfills.3462436425654af34.bundle.js
- vendor.sdgsdfg3453244354.bundle.js
- webpack-assets.json
- server
   - config.js
   - index.js
   - routes.js
   - socket.js
```

Now, I would like to run this application in a remote server.

So, copied the entire dist folder and tried the following.

> **forever start -o otput.log server/index.js**

The console logs,

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: server/index.js
```

In output.log.

```
Node NOT Exiting...
```

Nothing is happening.

My goal is to start this in a remote server. Not sure what am i missing here.

I tried forever in my local mac also.

> **forever start -o otput.log server/index.js**

I installed the below stuffs also.

> npm install express compression forever minimum-tls-version body-parser fs https path
>   method-override

Comment: use nodemon or nginx to serve the application on remote server

Comment: Nodemon is for development. I am looking for running in production.

Comment: nginx is suitable for production

Comment: Try to use forever in verbose mode - add --verbose in the command - or simply run node server/index.js and see what you get . Also have you placed the dist folder in the correct relative location ?